404 Page Does Not Work After Adding Rewrite Engine in htaccess
I had a 404.php document which was functioning properly. But when I added a rewrite engine to my htaccess file, the 404 no longer works. Instead I see a message that says "file not found."
The 404 and the htaccess files are both directly in the public_html folder. It worked great when it was just the ErrorDocument line but the rewrite seems to have broken it.
What am I missing?
Here are the contents of my htaccess file:
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^grandviewexteriorsystems.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.grandviewexteriorsystems.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Screenshot of what I'm seeing for the error, instead of my 404

I removed the rewrite rule and my 404 document appeared again upon entering an invalid url.
I tried a 404.html instead of php - same issue.
I tried a url to the 404 page, as well. Didn't work
I tried both 404 and 404.php


"I tried a url to the 404 page, as well. Didn't work" - What do you mean exactly by that? If you request /404.php directly then you should see your custom 404 page since the rewrite rule would not apply. (EDIT: I just tried that and I do see what appears to be your custom 404 page.) However, the simple "file not found" response is coming from an Nginx server, not Apache? You are also, erroneously, using relative URLs to your static assets in your custom 404 page, so a URL like /abc/abc.php is resulting in an unstyled page.


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


This appends .php to any URL that does not map to a file (and does not contains dots). This effectively bypasses your custom 404 on the initial request, although your custom 404 should then be triggered on the rewritten request that contains the .php extension - but that potentially exposes the .php request to the end user (depending on your error response) and results in an "erroneous" entry in the access log (since the user requested /abc, not /abc.php). However, it would seem an Nginx server is responding with the simple "file not found" response, not Apache. This is possibly to do with the way PHP is installed on your server and/or you are behind an Nginx proxy.
However, you should not be "blindly" appending .php to any URL that does not exist, but rather only appending .php if the corresponding URL exists. For example:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

Your rules are also in the wrong order. Your canonical redirect that prefixes the www extension should be the first rule. And this should be redirecting to https, not http. Your site is experiencing multiple redirects, but it would seem to be Nginx that is again performing these redirects (at least to HTTPS), not Apache?

It works for me
# custom 404 errors
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500

# URL rewrite rules
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


